# req.files.upload.length returns file count when zero, or more than one files are uploaded, when one file is uploaded, it returns file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In this loop, “req.files.upload.length” returns file count when 0, or more than one files are uploaded, however when one file is uploaded “req.files.upload.length” returns file size. Why?

upload handler:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log('file count: ' + req.files.upload.length);
    var file;
    var i = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < req.files.upload.length; x++){
        file = req.files.upload[x];
        console.log(file.name + ' (' + (file.size * 0.0009765625).toFixed(0) + ' kB, ' + file.type + ')');
    };
    console.log(req.files.upload.length + ' files uploaded to server');
    res.redirect('/forms');
});
```

When I upload one file I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/app.js:296:20
    at callbacks (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at Context.next (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:64:8)
    at SessionStrategy.pass (native)
    at /Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/strategies/session.js:48:12
URIError: URI malformed
    at /Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:119:14
    at Object.static [as handle] (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:5)
    at next (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at pass (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:219:24)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at Context.next (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:64:8)
    at SessionStrategy.pass (native)
    at /Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/strategies/session.js:48:12
```

Comment: I don't think the error has something to do with the code you pasted. What's here: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /Users/frode/Dropbox/Nettsider/expressmal/app.js:296:20
 ?

Comment: This is line 296: console.log(file.name + ' (' + (file.size * 0.0009765625).toFixed(0) + ' kB, ' + file.type + ')');

Comment: can you paste the form you're using to upload files and where you're 'processing' them? (in what route ..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Express/Connect, `req.files` will be an object with the `input[type=file]` `name` attribute as key, and the content as the value. If there are more than one `input[type=file]` with the same `name`, it will be an array instead. If you control the view, i.e. the web page with the `form`, you should be able to have either unique names for each file input, or know that you have more than one with the name "upload".

**Update:** I didn't think of the most obvious case, where the user has selected more than one file.

**Update:** Here's what `req.files` will look like for two different cases:

1. One file:

   ```
   req.files = {
     upload: {
       name: 'foo.txt'
       length: 1024
     }
   }
   ```
2. Two files:

   ```
   req.files = {
     upload: [
       {
         name: 'foo.txt'
         length: 1024
       },
       {
         name: 'bar.txt'
         length: 2048
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

As should be clear from this example, `req.files.upload` will have a `length` property in either case, but as you have found out they mean different things.

You probably want to iterate over an array in any case, to simplify your own code. This is easy to accomplish with `[].concat`:

```
// Make sure that files is always an array
var files = [].concat(req.files.upload);
for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
    file = files[x];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I do have control over the view. But how would I give individual files unique names when they are uploaded at the same time using the same file input?

Comment: @Frode: Good point. I honestly didn't think of that. ;) In that case, it seems you would have to check to see whether it's one file or many (.i.e. `req.files.upload` is an object or an array).

Comment: I also changed to a more robust array coercion (`[].concat`).